# transformation operations

Tags: kotlin

I need to calculate the perimeters of these rectangles, my teacher said I can do it using list transformation, but I don't understand how i can done it, please help

```
 data class Rectangle(val height: Int, val width: Int) {
    val perimeter: Int
        get() = height * 2 + width * 2
    val area: Int
        get() = height * width
}

val rectangles = listOf(
    Rectangle(11, 5),
    Rectangle(14, 3),
    Rectangle(5, 6),
    Rectangle(12, 21),
    Rectangle(35, 32),
    Rectangle(10, 12),
    Rectangle(4, 9)
)
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at [the collections docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html), especially [the operations overview](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-operations.html#common-operations) and try to find an operation that fits best what needs to be done for your assignment.

Comment: gff gff, do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: I've rolled back the self-vandalism. Please consider the value your question may have to future users of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the operations for the perimeter, only you have to iterate your list something like this:

```
for(rectangle in rectangles){
        println(rectangle.perimeter)
    }
```

Comment: How is this transforming the list, as per the question?